# Add a UIBarButtonItem next to UINavigation Back button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to add/show a button/custom view next to default back button. So it would look like this

< BACK | HOME

I want to preserve the default look and feel of back button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *home = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(HomePressed:)];
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:home, nil];
```

this code works for me, the back buttom UI didn't change. you would need to implement HomePressed:

Comment: Just a quick note, this is for iOS 5.0 and above... 4.3 doesn't support leftItemsSupplementBackButton selector...

Comment: self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES is money. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the leftBarButtonItems array on your view controller's UINavigationItem.

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects....];

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html for more information.

Comment: Yes that works, but the back button's style is changed when I do this, it would become normal bar button... I want the back button item's UI to be the same.